# Захват константного значения с плавающей точкой

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, const, clang

Почему этот код компилируется `gcc`

```
int main() {
    const auto x = 42;
    [](){ x; };
}
```

, а этот нет

```
int main() {
    const auto x = 42.;
    [](){ x; };
}
```

Если же использовать `constexpr`, то компилируются оба варианта.

Почему 1 вариант не компилируется `clang`?

Comment: [Этот код не компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/x5baeaf4q)

Comment: @user7860670 https://godbolt.org/z/d5E51sKjd

Comment: Ну наверное бага какая-то в gcc. vc++ солидарен с clang

Comment: VC++ 2019 благополучно компилирует оба варианта.

Comment: @user7860670 больше похоже на багу в clang. Ибо `+x` [уже компилируется](https://godbolt.org/z/x46z9Y46o). Да и [пример](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#example-4) похожий есть в стандарте.

Answer (score 1):

Константное целое значение доступно в лямбде даже если не захвачено. Это специальное правило. Для вещественных значений такого правила нет. Полагаю что это нужно чтобы объявлять массив указанной длины. `const int` можно использовать в таком качестве довольно давно.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

> ```
> A lambda expression can read the value of a variable without capturing
> it if the variable
>
>     * has const non-volatile integral or enumeration type and has been
>       initialized with a constant expression, or
>     * is constexpr and has no mutable members.
> ```

Comment: А с float везде так в с++.